# Can not retrieve KafkaStreams object in a Spring Boot application that uses Spring cloud stream binder

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka

so my problem is that I have some Kafka topics defined in my properties file, and I can read `KafkaStream<String, String>` from that topic no problem in my SpringBoot app. But I want to access `KafkaStreams` object so that i can print my `KafkaStreams` topology which is useful for development.
In one of my `@StreamListener`'s I try to retrieve stream-builder-process bean so that i can get underlying `KafkaStreams` object this way (as described here: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_accessing_the_underlying_kafkastreams_object) but it does not work unfortunately.
Here is the code:

```
@StreamListener
public void processEvent(@Input("order-paid-stream") KStream<String, String> inputStream) {
    StreamsBuilderFactoryBean streamsBuilderFactoryBean = applicationContext.getBean("&stream-builder-process", StreamsBuilderFactoryBean.class);
    KafkaStreams kafkaStreams = streamsBuilderFactoryBean.getKafkaStreams();
    System.out.println(kafkaStreams.toString());
    inputStream.foreach(this::handleMessage);
}
```

Upon application start I receive the following message:

[image]

I also tried to retrieve `KafkaStreams` object the same way on one of my REST controller methods after the application was started with similar error (bean of that name not found).

Any help?

Comment: No one had this problem before?

Comment: can you share your config file?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue and figured out I needed to also include the class name which the process function was defined in e.g. `stream-builder-MyStreamProcessor-process`.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with a delayed separate thread to ensure that kafkaStream object is created and topology is completed.

streamsBuilderFactoryBean.getKafkaStreams() returns KafkaStream object
streamsBuilderFactoryBean.getSingletonInstance().topology returns topology object
streamsBuilderFactoryBean.getStreamsConfiguration() returns all set kafka-streams configurations

```java
class StreamsListener {
    @StreamListener
    @SendTo("output")
    public KStream<String, String> process(@Input("input') KStream<String,String> rawCloudEventKStream {

        new Thread(() -> {
            try { Thread.sleep(30000); } catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

            StreamsBuilderFactoryBean streamsBuilderFactoryBean = context.getBean("&stream-builder-StreamsListener-process", StreamsBuilderFactoryBean.class);
            System.out.println("KafkaStreams configs: " + streamsBuilderFactoryBean.getStreamsConfiguration());
            KafkaStreams kafkaStreams = streamsBuilderFactoryBean.getKafkaStreams();
        }).start();

        ...
    }
}
```